# How to use special characters when setting pageTitle?

Tags: cakephp, special-characters, html-entities, page-title

I tried both `&rsquo;` and `’` but they show up as `&rsquo;` in the browser title bar.

Comment: Edited your question, please make sure it's what you mean.

Comment: which browser you use? Because I checked in IE & mizilla. It shows ' in title bar

Comment: @deceze What did you change? The grey highlight? Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: HTML works as HTML here, your `&rsquo;` were all showing up as `’` and your question made little sense. You need to escape HTML with a backtick.

Comment: Ok I realize h($title_for_layout); is messing it up. I understand it's a security thing but are typographically correct characters still possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this one (both in the controller or model) and I've seen the html characters correctly in the title browser.

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Testing: &raquo; &laquo; &rsquo;');
```